# Facebook - tag people in posts by a page using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, facebook-page

I have a page and I have an iPad app. I am using the graph API to login to facebook as a user and post a photo taken from the iPad to the page. The thing is that the photos are shown in "Posted by others" section, which doesn't show detail by default.

So what am I doing is posting on the page itself with administrator privileges. My question is - how do I mention/tag people in the post?

They have logged themselves in the app already so I can use their credentials but the post has to be done by the page admin.

Anybody has an idea of how to do such thing?

Comment: You need to use a page access token. It is described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Yep, I know that, but how to mention/tag the people in the photo?